# How to paste multiple values from an object to a string and have a single sentence output?

Tags: r, paste, r-glue

I need to paste the three values in `tables` to a string such as this: "The correct tables include:" and print it as a single sentence.

```
tables = c("Brif", "Amni","Calp")
```

Desired output:

```
The correct tables include: Brif, Amni, Calp
```

I use the following code, but it pastes the values separately to the string an thus I get the following output. Could you please help me fix this?

```
library(glue)
glue("The correct tables include: {tables}")

The correct tables include: Brif
The correct tables include: Amni
The correct tables include: Calp
```

Comment: use `toString`: `glue("The correct tables include: {toString(tables)}")`

Comment: Very handy function! Thanks!